# Oracle create table with foreign key error - Invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys

I'm getting an error saying invalid identifier when I try to add this table. Its been bugging me for too long now so I thought I'd ask.

```
CREATE TABLE HORSE 
(  
horse_id numeric PRIMARY KEY,
horse_name character(30) not null,
horse_gender character(1) not null,
horse_height decimal not null,
horse_image character(40), 
CONSTRAINT horse_breed FOREIGN KEY (breed_id) REFERENCES breed(breed_id) 
);
```

The error message is;

```
Error at Command Line:34 Column:37
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "BREED_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thanks and sorry for asking what is probably a really dumb question.

Comment: Also the error is with the line CONSTRAINT horse_breed FOREIGN KEY (breed_id) REFERENCES breed(breed_id)

Comment: Please post the full error message (**edit your question**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `breed_id` in `HORSE` table

```
CREATE TABLE HORSE 
(  
horse_id numeric PRIMARY KEY,
horse_name character(30) not null,
horse_gender character(1) not null,
horse_height decimal not null,
horse_image character(40), 
breed_id numeric null
CONSTRAINT horse_breed FOREIGN KEY (breed_id) REFERENCES breed(breed_id) 
);
```

Comment: whats the significance of the null tag on the breed_id you've put there?

Comment: `null` means you don't have to fill the column with data, other words it could be null, and other word horse shouldn't have breed ;)

Comment: isn't that just the same as 'not' having `not null`?

Comment: @pjmil116 Yes I could say that :)